# Hotkey for "Previous search result word" in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> gets you to find words, and a simple enter brings you to the next word. What hotkey takes you to the previous word?

Comment: **NOTE** that the hotkey for find changes depending on locale. Example, `da-DK` has `CTRL-B` for find, `CTRL-F` for bold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the navigation pane open, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> is in fact pressing the down arrow (triangle) button visible over the top-right corner of the result list.

Use left arrow key <kbd>←</kbd> (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) to switch the selection to up arrow (triangle) button and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to the previous word.

Comment: Thank you! What a supreme usability decision by Microsoft might I add!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Ctrl+PgUp and Ctrl+PgDn for this, with some setup.

Below the vertical scroll bar, there are three buttons: an upward-pointing double arrow, a circle, and a downward-pointing double arrow. When you have performed a search operation, the double arrows become blue. This means that, in this case, *when the caret is in the document text*, you can press Ctrl+PgUp and Ctrl+PgDn to go to the previous and the next match, respectively.

You can also click the circle button to let the double-arrow buttons, and the hotkeys, go between other things than search matches.

Answer (score 1):

In Word 2016 (16.0.5134.1000) 64 bit. The following hotkeys work for me.

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> to find next occurrence.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> to find previous occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

In ***Office 2016***, I miss the <kbd>Ctrl+PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+PgDn</kbd>. Found the following work around:

- Use the *Find* feature as normal (<kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>), specifying what I want to search for and then looking for the first occurrence of the string.
- When the first occurrence is displayed, I press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key (or click on *Cancel*).
- To find the next occurrence, I press <kbd>Shift+F4</kbd>.

This works fine for me now. But am still searching for a way to go on the reverse direction, like <kbd>Ctrl+PgUp</kbd>.

Source: https://wordribbon.tips.net/T012327_A_Fast_Find-Next.html